# Mssing icons with booting error

Tags: unity

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 few days ago and it works fine until now, when i get error with Ubuntu part 6 is disable and some of my icon in unity is missing.

[image]

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall unity by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

After that logout and login back to take effect.